# Culture sensitive capitalization ToUpperInvariant/ToLowerInvariant

Tags: c#, .net

What specific English alphabet letters need the invariant versions of ToUpper() and ToLower() case-conversion calls for proper behaviour ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` will capitalize to `İ` (note dotted *capital* I) if you're running under under a Turkish localization.  See the [Turkish test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).  There may be others.